# list database tables that don't need to be qualified with schema name

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-metadata

I connect to a PostgreSQL server with: `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/mydb?currentSchema=app96`.
I need to list tables that are present and create those that are missing during the initialization of my server.

Here's my code:

```
final ResultSet rs2 =
    conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, "", null, new String[] { "TABLE" });
while (rs2.next()) {
    System.out
        .println(rs2.getString("TABLE_SCHEM") + "." + rs2.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
}
```

It prints:

```
app96.t1
app96.t2
public.administration$account
public.appmodule$uploadedfile
public.audittrail$audittrailsuperclass
...
```

From javadoc of `getTables`:

> schemaPattern ... "" retrieves those without a schema

But it seems that `getTables` treats empty string the same way as null. Is there a pure JDBC way to filter by current schema or do I have to implement DB-specific filters myself?

Comment: Well there is no such thing as a table without a schema in Postgres. The need to fully qualify a table reference in a query depends on the schemas specified in `search_path`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is correct as per JDBC specification in Java it says this.

> schemaPattern - a schema name pattern; must match the schema name as
> it is stored in the database; "" retrieves those without a schema;
> null means that the schema name should not be used to narrow the
> search

but PostgreSQL implementation `PgDatabaseMetaData` doesn't seem to be honoring this.

getTables method has below check, where it is checking for NULL as well as Non empty String. ( may be this is how PostgreSQL implemented it)

```
  if (schemaPattern != null && !schemaPattern.isEmpty()) {
      select += " AND n.nspname LIKE " + escapeQuotes(schemaPattern);
    }
```

[PgDatabaseMetaData implementation code from Github](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/2a8ecbe2321ed92bc7051d3415a0484a5464346b/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgDatabaseMetaData.java)

Comment: This is correct, as there is no such thing as a table without a schema in Postgres. So passing `""` could never return anything.